# App as shortcut for website

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to create an app that will act as a shortcut for my website.So basically what i want to do is when user click on app icon it opens my website in safari or other browser and close the app.

I know its not recommended to close app as per apple guideline but i want to do it gracefully like it opens browser now its work is done; close the app.

Does anybody have any idea?

I can open the browser using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"]];
```

but don't have any idea on how to close app gracefully.

Comment: Yes important note is that i don't want to use uiwebview.

Comment: It is absolutely not possible to make such an app. Note that even Apple's automatic checking instantly dismisses such apps: you won't even make it past the upload to the human review process. An interesting fact is that not even Apple themselves can do what you suggest, with an Apple app.

Answer (score -1):

Note: you can NOT do the following in iOS apps (2016):

---

You can close your app by using this code.

```
exit(0);
```

Comment: I dont think so... The app might be rejected.

Comment: Apple guidelines do not allow you to close the app like this. Surely, your app will be rejected.

Comment: It will be instantly rejected.

Comment: Check the link : No way to quit the app https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html

Comment: does abort is allowed in production environment??

Comment: if your are using exit(0), the app is rejected from App Store , the reason the  does not know the app is closed , the think about the app is crashed

Comment: Even if he does not use `exit(0)` the app should get rejected because it doesn't provide sufficient functionality.